# How to create Scatter Chart in PPT slide using OpenXML in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk

I want to create Scatter chart in PPT slide using OpenXML in ASP.NET, but I am facing some issue in X-Axis and Y-Axis data plotting. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I think it is useful to see this link : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-charts-in-powerpoint-using-c-sharp/

Comment: The link above gives a description of plotting in ppt. You must have x, y coordinates